# Different domains and content with one database

Tags: database, organic-groups, nodes, multi-sites, domain-access

I would like to have different content for each domain. This is my scenario:

I would like to have these domains:

```
country1.hello.com
country2.hello.com
country3.hello.com
country4.hello.com
```

They all need to have the **same** content types, taxonomy, rules, ... . (Content will be different)

The domains are available in different langauges. So country1 has for ex. languages **dutch/french/english** (all the other domains **TOO**!).

I want this all in one database. And I also need one domain hello.com where you can see the content of all the domains!

Does someone has experience with this? I've seen the modules [Organic Groups](https://www.drupal.org/project/og) & [Domain Access](https://www.drupal.org/project/domain) but haven't played with them.

I would like to ask for your opinion before I am halfway my project and hear it's not a good solution.

Comment: Domain Access is a good solution. you can [extend it further](https://www.drupal.org/node/10685700)

Comment: Is it possible to show content of all domains on one domain?

Comment: Yes it is possible. give it a try.